# Chromium how to know/set the scroll position in opened pdf file?

Tags: c#, vb.net, chromium, cefsharp

I am using CEFSharp implementation of ChromiumWebBrowser. I am able to open a pdf file with it.
I want to save the scroll position (and zoom status) in opened pdf to restore it later/in a next session.
How can I do this?
I need this functionality in my software but it is OK to use other solution than chromium/cefsharp.

Comment: Chrome it's self doesn't remember pdf state that I'm aware of https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=65244 has been open for years. You can probably use pdf.js to achieve something workable see https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/ if all you care about is viewing pdf files then switching to a purpose built viewer is probably better,  use your fav search engine and search for pdfium c# for one option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am working with Pdfium from Patagames and works like a charm.